# Is the Excel function IFERROR volatile?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a fairly large Excel sheet which keeps track of our golfcompetition. To speed up the sheet (for use on my old laptop) I am trying to limit the number of  automatic calculations. E.g. the total score is only calculated if you enter the last hole (by adding an IF).

However, my DirectWindow (the one which is fed by debug.print statements) shows me there is a lot of calculation done after every entry. It seems the calculation is kicked off by functions (UDFs) that start with =IFERROR.

So my question is: is far as I know IFERROR is not a volatile function, I cannot find any proof of it anyway. But does anybody have the experience of the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - `IFERROR` is non-volatile. I have just tested this as follows:

1. Added the following VBA to Sheet1:

   `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
       MsgBox "Calculating"
   End Sub`
2. Set cell A1 to `=NA()`
3. Set cell B1 to `=IFERROR(A1,"OHNO!")

This results in the message box showing. However, entering data in another cell *does not*.

I then changed A1 to a number, "1", and got the message box. Entering data in another cell after this makes no difference.

I then added to cell C1 `=NOW()`. This resulted in calculating *every time I enter data in another cell*, highlighting I've now added a volatile formula.

[image]

Comment: I think volatile is different: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. It recalculates when something else is do so, and not it cause recalculation as you tested.

Comment: @MátéJuhász "A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in *any cells* on the worksheet." Doesn't that mean that the function re-evaluates regardless of what cell changes (Like `Now()` does in this instance), and non volatile means it only changes when the cells it references changes (Like `IFERROR()` does in this instance?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection2) only lists around 7 functions as volatile, these are ones that trigger regardless of which cell you edit on the sheet.

Comment: You can confirm that this works by using `=iferror(indirect("A1"),"OHNO!")`, `indirect()` is volatile, and the msgbox comes up every time, whether or not you changed anything in A1.